# Speed up Queries - Average calculation in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi how can I optimse my two queries for average and margin calculation?

The table has over 3 million records.
On a small data set the following queries work fine but on the big data set the queries block because of time out.

Table script:

```
CREATE TABLE `Prices` (`country` text,`Date` int,`items` varchar(250),`priceEuro` int,`url` varchar(250))
```

PriceAVG View calculation:

```
CREATE VIEW 
PriceAVG AS
Select distinct 
Prices.country, 
Prices.items, 
(SELECT ROUND(AVG(priceEuro)) FROM Prices AS T1 WHERE T1.items = Prices.items AND T1.country = Prices.country) AS average 
FROM Prices;
```

Margin calculation:

```
CREATE VIEW 
Margin AS
SELECT  
Prices.country, 
Prices.items, 
Prices.priceEuro, 
PriceAVG.average, 
(PriceAVG.average - Prices.priceEuro) AS margin,
Prices.url  
FROM Prices
INNER JOIN PriceAVG ON Prices.items = PriceAVG.items AND Prices.country = PriceAVG.country  
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PriceAVG WHERE Prices.items = PriceAVG.items AND PriceAVG.country = 'Canada' )  
ORDER BY `margin` DESC
```

Comment: Optimizing queries questions needs in precise DBMS version info, complete CREATE TABLE scripts, execution plan and data statistic publication.

Comment: the table PriceAVG looks suspiciously like it's created from the first query but is not presented as such? Also aggregation with group by seems appropriate but you don't use it?

Comment: Do you really use a table without any indexes?

Answer (score 1):

Simplified version of your data might look like

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;

CREATE TABLE T(COUNTRY INT, PRICE INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1,10),(1,20),(2,30);
```

The avg can be calculated in a subquery and joined to main query like this

```
SELECT T.COUNTRY,PRICE,AVGPRICE, PRICE-AVGPRICE MARGIN
FROM T
JOIN
(
SELECT COUNTRY , AVG(PRICE) AVGPRICE
FROM T 
GROUP BY COUNTRY
) A ON A.COUNTRY = T.COUNTRY;

+---------+-------+----------+---------+
| COUNTRY | PRICE | AVGPRICE | MARGIN  |
+---------+-------+----------+---------+
|       1 |    10 |  15.0000 | -5.0000 |
|       1 |    20 |  15.0000 |  5.0000 |
|       2 |    30 |  30.0000 |  0.0000 |
+---------+-------+----------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

If this is too simple for you consider adding representative sample data as text to the question.

Comment: thank you. For my case I would need to distinguish as well for items. I am building the average of the same items in same country. Right now I tried your query, but I also get a time out. So I need to get a faster query.

Comment: Your table does not appear to have any indexes , I suggest one on country since that is what you are filtering by.

Comment: If you have run a query on representative sample data and it produces the output you expect I suggest you raise a new question publishing the query and an explain plan so we can look at it from a performance perspective. Attempting to tune your current queries is not worth it given the known poor performance of views in mysql and the queries within the views being sub optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using a sub-select

```
Select p.country
     , p.items
     , ROUND(AVG(p.priceEuro)) AS average 
FROM Prices p
GROUP BY p.country
       , p.items;
```

Should calculate the average per country/items. For the margin it is probably easiest to use a window function:

```
SELECT p.country
     , p.items
     , p.priceEuro 
     , p.average, 
     , p.average - p.priceEuro AS margin
     , p.url  
FROM (
  SELECT country
     , items
     , priceEuro 
     , AVG(priceEuro) OVER (PARTITION BY country, items) AS average
     , url
  FROM Prices
) AS p
```

Comment: very good. Awesome I come up with the same average query. Small data set of records, no problem but again on the big data set (3millions), I get a timeout for calculation. Any better faster idea?

Comment: I dont think you can do much better than with these queries. What index(es) do you have on the table?

Comment: Can you filter the result? I.e. calculate the average price for a particular country, or do you need all countries and all items all the time? Accessing 3 million rows is gonna take some time no matter what

Comment: Thanks a lot. I contacted the server team yesterday. We figured out that the reason for the speed was a database error.